# Type definitions module not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React project, written in TypeScript, with the following file structure:

```
├── BoldedText.tsx
├── highlighter
│   ├── Highlighter.js
│   └── index.t.ts
├── App.tsx
```

My BoldedText component is using the Highlight component (through the type definition index.d.ts since the component is written in JavaScript).

import React from 'react'
import Highlighter from "./highlighter/index";

```
interface Props {
    boldedWords: string[]
    text: string
}

const Highlight : React.ComponentType<any> = (props) => (
    <strong className="highlighted-text">{props.children}</strong>
);

const BoldedText = (props: Props) => {
    const { boldedWords, text } = props
        return (
            <Highlighter
                searchWords={boldedWords}
                autoEscape={true}
                highlightTag={Highlight}
                textToHighlight={text}
            />
        )
}
```

and this is my type definition file (index.d.ts):

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface FindChunks {
  autoEscape?: boolean;
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  sanitize?: (text: string) => string;
  searchWords: string[];
  textToHighlight: string;
}

export interface Chunk {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}

export interface HighlighterProps {
    /** The class name to be applied to an active match. Use along with activeIndex */
    activeClassName?: string;
    /** Specify the match index that should be actively highlighted. Use along with activeClassName */
    activeIndex?: number;
    /** The inline style to be applied to an active match. Use along with activeIndex */
    activeStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
    /** Escape characters in searchWords which are meaningful in regular expressions */
    autoEscape?: boolean;
    /** CSS class name applied to the outer/wrapper <span> */
    className?: string;
    /** Search should be case sensitive; defaults to false */
    caseSensitive?: boolean;
    /**
     * Use a custom function to search for matching chunks. This makes it possible to use arbitrary logic
     * when looking for matches. See the default findChunks function in highlight-words-core for signature.
     * Have a look at the custom findChunks example on how to use it.
     */
    findChunks?: (options: FindChunks) => Chunk[];
    /** CSS class name applied to highlighted text */
    highlightClassName?: string;
    /** Inline styles applied to highlighted text */
    highlightStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
    /**
     * Type of tag to wrap around highlighted matches; defaults to mark but can also be a React element
     * (class or functional)
     */
    highlightTag?: string | React.ComponentType<any>;
    /**
     * Process each search word and text to highlight before comparing (eg remove accents); signature
     * (text: string): string
     */
    sanitize?: (text: string) => string;
    /** Array of search words. The search terms are treated as RegExps unless autoEscape is set. */
    searchWords: string[];
    /** Text to highlight matches in */
    textToHighlight: string;
    /** CSS class name applied to unhighlighted text */
    unhighlightClassName?: string;
    /** Inline styles applied to unhighlighted text */
    unhighlightStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
    /** Allows to pass through any parameter to wrapped component */
    [index: string]: any;
}

declare class Highlighter extends React.Component<HighlighterProps> {}

export default Highlighter;
```

However, when running the application I get the following error:

```
./src/components/util/BoldedText.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './highlighter/index'
```

I have tried restructuring my files, but I still get module not found for index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Webpack configured that it also looks for t.ts extensions?
Check your webpack and ensure that all needed extensions are resolved

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
}
```

And also ensure that your entry path is correct. Mostly the default is `public/src/`
This should be also configured in the webpack.

Comment: my tsconfig.json has "resolveJsonModule": true